# using a DOM event callback inside an object

Tags: javascript, object, events, p5.js

In p5.js, How do you make a DOM element callback a function if both the DOM element and the function are inside the same object ? for example :

```
function Snape()
{
    this.myInput = createInput("");
    this.myInput.changed(this.erase);
    this.erase = function()
    {

    }
}
```

when I type something in `this.myInput`, I would like it to call the function `this.erase`, but I get the error `11913: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined`

is it possible ?
——————————————————————————————————————————
EDIT : The main issue is solved if I declare `this.erase` before I call it :

```
function Snape()
{

    this.myInput = createInput("");
    this.erase = function()
    {

    }
    this.myInput.changed(this.erase);
}
```

but that’s a really messy way to do it.

Moreover, I wasn’t able to implement what was suggested in the answer :
In p5.js, the way we invoke a callback is like this :

```
this.myInput.changed(this.erase);
```

if I do this

```
this.myInput.changed(this.erase());
```

I get this error : `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

So, when I try to call `this.erase` using this (as was suggested) :

```
this.myInput.changed(function(){ myself.erase(); });
```

I get the same error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`
I tried all the different possibilities :

```
this.myInput.changed(function(){ myself.erase() }); 
this.myInput.changed(function(){ myself.erase; }); 
this.myInput.changed(function(){ myself.erase });
```

neither of those are working.

I can’t use the => function because I need to call `this.erase` a lot of times in different instance of the object, and from multiple DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save `this` into a variable so you can then reference it:

```js
function Snape() {
    var myself = this;
    this.myInput = createInput("");
    this.myInput.changed(function(){ myself.erase(); });
    this.erase = function()
    {
      console.log("erased");
    }
}
```

Another (less elegant) solution would be this:

```js
var input;

function setup () {
  createCanvas(500, 300);
  input = new Snape () ;
}

function Snape () {
    this.myInput = createInput("");
    this.myInput.changed(tunnel);
    this.erase = function()
    {
      console.log("erased");
    }

}

function tunnel () {
  input.erase();
}
```